# How to send and receive data between a gba and gamecube

Tags: nintendo, game-boy-advance

I'm using a gba to gamecube cable to do some homebrew. I am fairly sure that the gamecube side works fine, but the gba side is confusing me.

How do I correctly send and receive data on the GBA side? [GBATek](http://problemkaputt.de/gbatek.htm#siojoybusmode) suggests the use of some memory mapped registers, but no matter what I try I end up losing or otherwise mangling data.

Comment: Ooh, that's a tough one. I'm not sure how well-documented it is to be honest.